# Drawing tree like structure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I have to draw the following figure. What I have now is uggly. Somehow the structure should be more balanced. Is there a way to do this with tikz-qtree? The point is that it is multiple dominance and furthermore the node lables are not within the tree but next to it. The top node does not have a label.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)
\rput[B](1,0){German}
\rput[B](3,0){Dutch}
\rput[B](5,0){Danish}
\rput[B](7,0){English}
\rput[B](9,0){French}
\rput[B](1.5,2){SOV}
\rput[B](1.5,1.6){VC}
\rput[B](3,4){V2}
\rput[B](7.7,2){SVO}

\psline(1,0.4)(4,5)
\psline(2,2)(3,0.4)
\psline(3.4,4)(5,0.4)
\psline(5,0.4)(7,2)
\psline(7,2)(7,0.4)
\psline(4,5)(9,0.4)
%\psgrid
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's PSTricks code but the tags are TikZ. Is that on purpose or you just give an example ?

Comment: This is just how it is supposed to look like. I started tikz-qtree and I am quite happy with the way it works (without having to name nodes explicitly) but I have no idea how to do this with tikz-qtree or tikz without qtree.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possibility using `TikZ`; I used the `trees` library (even though, formally, this isn't a tree):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=60pt},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=40pt}
]
\coordinate
child {node (v2) {V2}
  child {node[text width=2.2em,align=center] {SOV\\VC} 
    child {node {German}} 
    child {node {Dutch}}}
  child[missing]
}
child {
  child[missing]
  child {node {SVO} 
    child {node (dan) {Danish}} 
    child {node {English}} 
    child {node {French}}}
};
\draw (v2) -- (dan);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the library trees like Gonzalo but below I give you the traduction of your code in tikz and after some possibilities without trees with only tikz. The last code is  the better attempt.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=base] at (1,0) {German};
  \node[anchor=base] at (3,0) {Dutch};
  \node[anchor=base] at (5,0) {Danish};
  \node[anchor=base] at (7,0) {English};
  \node[anchor=base] at (9,0) {French};
  \node[anchor=base] at (1.5,2) {SOV};
  \node[anchor=base] at (1.5,1.6) {VC};
  \node[anchor=base] at (3,4) {V2};
  \node[anchor=base] at (7.7,2) {SVO};

  \draw (1,0.4) -- (4,5);
  \draw (2,2) -- (3,0.4);
  \draw (3.4,4) -- (5,0.4);
  \draw (5,0.4) -- (7,2);
  \draw (7,2) -- (7,0.4);
  \draw (4,5) -- (9,0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The last code is better like this:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}]
     \path  
      (1,0)     node {German}     (3,0)     node {Dutch}
      (5,0)     node {Danish}     (7,0)     node {English}
      (9,0)     node {French}     (1.5,2)   node {SOV}
      (1.5,1.6) node {VC}         (3,4)     node {V2}
      (7.7,2)   node {SVO};

     \draw (1,0.4) -- (4,5)   (2,2) -- (3,0.4)  (3.4,4) -- (5,0.4)
           (5,0.4) -- (7,2)   (7,2) -- (7,0.4)  (4,5) -- (9,0.4);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

We can get something like Gonzalo :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base}]
    \path  
     (4,5)     coordinate (main)
     (1,0)     node (G) {German}     (3,0)     node (DU) {Dutch}
     (5,0)     node (D) {Danish}     (7,0)     node (E)  {English}
     (9,0)     node (F) {French}     (1.5,2)   node (SO) {SOV}
     (1.5,1.6) node (V) {VC}         (3,4)     node (V2) {V2}
     (7.7,2)   node (S) {SVO};

    \draw (main) -- (V2)  -- (V2) -- (SO)   (main) -- (S) -- (E)
            (V2) -- (D)      (S) -- (F) (S)--(D)  (V) -- (G) (V) -- (DU)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But it's better to not use coordinates, without tree's library the better way is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base},node distance=2cm and 2cm,on grid]
    \path node (GE) {German}  
          node[right=of  GE]             (DU)  {Dutch}    
          node[right=3cm of  DU]         (DA)  {Danish}
          node[right=of  DA]             (EN)  {English}
          node[right=of  EN]             (FR)  {French}
          node[above=of DU,align=center] (VC)  {SOV\\VC}  
          node[above =of EN]             (SVO) {SVO}
          node[above right=of VC]        (V2)  {V2} 
          coordinate[above right=of V2]  (main)   ; 

    \draw (main) -- (V2) -- (VC) -- (GE)      (main) -- (SVO) -- (DA)
                            (VC)--(DU)                  (SVO) -- (EN) 
                    (V2) -- (DA)                        (SVO) -- (FR) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This package is so complex and with so many possibilities and it is really great to see it applied to one's own problem. I learned a lot!